# reactjs -- Disable button when an element's length reaches limit in this.state

Tags: reactjs

But the element is not filled until an ajax call is made in `componentDidMount`

It seems like the render happens before the ajax call returns something, thus the button is never disabled. How do I make sure the button is disabled correctly?

code:

```
<button className="someclass" onClick={this.handleClick} disabled={this.state.apps.length < 5}>some text</button>}
```

and in `componentDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch("some_url", {
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify({"user": "some email"}),
        headers: {'Content-Type': ' application/json'}
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
        (result) => {
            this.setState({apps: JSON.parse(result)});
        },
        (error) => {
            console.log("error", error);
        }
        );
}
```

There is no issue making the call and returning the elements `apps`, but the timing makes the disable not happening

EDIT: My logic was wrong....should check for `>=` instead of `<`....... I'm stupid.......

Comment: do you get any errors on console ? what s your app initial state

Comment: @SakhiMansoor I did not get any error. Trying to `console.log` the length of `this.state.apps` before the render and got multiple `0` before it finally received some response from API call and prints out `5`. Somehow my button is not updated accordingly

Comment: please share console output your state after fetching the data I want to see APP object

Comment: It should work as it is. Are you sure isn't it started with a disabled state but you can't see it since it is a happening too fast?

Comment: okay from a second look, my logic check for `<` which should be `>=` instead...... I should only disable it when it exceeds that number.......

Comment: Again, should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a second look, the problem is probably related with parsing your array. Why do you parse it? It does not work on arrays. Just set your state in a regular way:

```
this.setState({apps: result});
```

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    apps: [],
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch( "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts" )
      .then( res => res.json() )
      .then( apps => {
        this.setState({ apps })
      })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={this.handleClick}
          disabled={this.state.apps.length >= 5}
        >some text</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I think this is correct. Though my problem was that my logic was incorrect, I'll mark this as asnwer.

Answer (score 0):

you have to initialize apps in the constructor

```
constructor() { 
    this.state = {apps: ''};
  }
```

Comment: my `apps` is indeed initialized, but as `state = {apps: []}`